# Unordered map taking lot of space

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have created a map of unit64_t to uint64_t. This is the code I have written for assesing the space complexity:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "sparsehash/internal/sparseconfig.h"
#include "sparsehash/sparse_hash_map"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    std::string input,reference;

    while (getline(cin,input)) {
    reference += input;
    input.clear();
    }

    cout<<"length of reference = "<<reference.length()<<endl;
    unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t> m;
    //google::sparse_hash_map<uint64_t, pair<short,long>> m;

    for (auto it = reference.begin(); it != reference.end(); it++) {
        m[it-reference.begin()]= it-reference.begin();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this with /usr/bin/time , this is the output produced by the program:

```
length of reference = 4641652
    Command being timed: "./a.out"
    User time (seconds): 2.97
    System time (seconds): 0.15
    Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:03.13
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 251816
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 68259
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 104
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

The unordered map seems to take up 250MB of space. This seems to be unusually high. Why would this happen. The same code with google sparse hash takes only 89MB of space, which is more reasonable.

I don't understand why the C++ unordered map take up so much space?

Comment: I don't see anything to indicate that the memory usage should be more or less than 250mb. Why do you think this is a lot of memory? How many elements are you putting in the map? Have you taken into account allocation padding and housekeeping of the map? Have you considered giving us relevant information?

Comment: Yes, the input is a string of size 4.5Mb.  I'm putting each of its positions into the map.

Comment: @user1995120: if you're storing positions in a string that's dramatically less than 4GB (max addressable with 32 bit numbers), and care about memory usage, why use 64 bit values?  (If you want to preserve the capability to handle >4GB strings, you may still be able to use templates to create 32 and 64 bit versions of your code and use the optimal one at runtime).

Comment: @TonyD : yeah, using 32 bit number would save space. However for my work I would need 64 - bit numbers. In any case, this is just a sample program I wrote to find out the memory usage due to unordered map in my program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `4641652` entries. So the total raw data size is `4641652*2*8 byte ~= 74 MB`.

There's a important fact about hash-tables. Fast hash tables have lots of hash buckets, and hash-tables with a small number of hash buckets are slow.

It basically all comes down to hash-collisions. If you have many hash buckets (and you have a good hashing function), than hash-collisions happen rarely. Therefore the lookup is really really fast. 
On the otherside if your table is small (not many hash buckets), than hash-collisions happen regularly. Thus the lookup function is a lot slower.

Now `std::unordered_map` is manly desiged as a fast hash-table, so it has quite a lot overhead. There are much more hash buckets than entries. In this case the overhead is about `250 / 74 ~= 3.3x`, which seems to be quite normal.

But `sparsehash` is designed to have as little overhead as possible (about ~2 bit per entry). But of course this means that it is quite a lot slower.

If your using a hash-map, you should always think about, if you want speed or you want to be memory efficient.

Comment: There's also the overhead in each bucket for the collisions (likely a pointer) for another ~37MB or ~121MB total, and for the unused buckets (because there are many empty buckets in the bucket list).  Also the memory used by the older, shorter bucket array from the last time the map was rehashed.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Depends on the implementation. Collision handling via linked lists would act as you describe, but collision handling via chaining (so a hash collision places the second entry somewhere else in a predictable way) wouldn't have that overhead (though it would need to use markers for previously filled buckets so the chaining algorithm can find a displaced entry if the original entry is subsequently deleted). Python uses chaining rather than lists; wouldn't be surprised if some vendors did the same at least for some cases.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: ["chaining"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists) is another term used for having linked lists of colliding elements - what you describe (and is used by python) is known as *open addressing* or *closed hashing*.  And no `std::unordered_map` implementations use that technique - it's incompatible with the requirements of the Standard (specifically, a default `max_load_factor` of 1.0 and only rehashing when that's exceeded).

Comment: Yeah, I was having trouble remembering the terminology, and quickly checked Python's [dictnotes.txt](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictnotes.txt) which uses the term "chaining" to describe open addressing, because of course it does. I'm not surprised C++ prohibits it though; there would be implementation issues with doing so given that the templates specialize by type; you wouldn't actually gain much since you couldn't reuse storage to indicate a dummy, which means you're paying the cost of dummy flags and at that point, you may as well use linked lists.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes, open addressing certainly works best when there's a convenient sentinel value (or two - one for unused, another for deleted), but when you do have that - and especially when populating tables without deleting elements - it can be an order of magnitude faster.  Still, key advantages of chaining (linked lists) are stable element addresses despite rehashes (iterators are invalidated, but not pointers and references), and - with GCC's impl - `O(size())` iteration (open addressing tends to be O(buckets), which isn't so good if you've grown the table then shrunk dramatically.